# Решение нелинейных систем уравнений

Tags: math

Сразу говорю - вопрос сложный.

Есть система уравнений вида.

```
-w -v + 44 =0
 w -x + y -20.5 =0
 v -y -z -11 = 0
 x + z -12.5 = 0
-0.001716*(w^2) + 0.003065*(v^2) + 0.072168*(y^2) = 0
-0.057172*(x^2) + 0.072168*(y^2) + 0.038655*(z^2) = 0
```

Приближенные начальные значения есть и достаточно близки.
Неизвестных 5. А уравнений 6. Причем с усложнением системы "разрыв" будет расти.
Степень уравнений не более 2.

Есть ли у кого идеи (может сталкивался) как с таким бороться (аналитический метод, к сожалению, не подходит)?

Обычно, такое решается методом Ньютона, но он подходит только для квадратных матриц...

Comment: Фигасе вопросики пошли =) Я бы решил методом рандома - пустил был подбирать числа, пока не совпадут условия =)

Comment: 0.003065*v^2 -- это читается как:

0.003065*(v^2)

или 

(0.003065*v)^2

?

Comment: У степени приоритет выше, поэтому скобки не ставил.
Поправлено в вопросе. const*(v^2)

Comment: `-0.001716*(w^2) + 0.003065*(v^2) + 0.072168*(y^2) = 0`

В принципе, тут и без решения уравнения очевидно, что 
`w = 0; v = 0; y = 0;`.

Аналогично и последнее уравнение. Если я не прав, приведите контрпример.

В итоге у нас все неизвестные равны нули и система уравнений выглядит неверной. Либо вместо нуля должно быть что-то типа `0.00000000002652` (т.е. очень малое число).

Если все же там не ноль, то можно попытаться избавится от `^2` и решить систему уравнений метод Гаусса или Краулера.

Comment: Неа, бывают еще комплексные корни... =)

Comment: Бывают, но тут комплексных корней не будет, во вторых интересны только действительная область.

Значения w, v, y разумеется не равны 0, так как это противоречит например первому уравнению.

Вы вероятно знак "-" в начале пропустили. Числа могут быть практически любого порядка.

Если брать навскидку, то z~7, y~1, x~5.5, w~25, v~19. Это по первым четырем. На самом деле все корни дробные, чтоб уменьшить разбежности в последних уравнениях до приемлимого.

Comment: Согласен с вами. "-" пропустил, признаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если приближенные методы подхоят, то можно решить численными методами. Вот несколько ссылок:
[Решение систем нелинейных уравнений.](http://www.nsu.ru/matlab/Exponenta_RU/educat/systemat/hanova/equation/loc.asp.htm)
[Численные методы. Учебное пособие.](http://www.uchites.ru/chislennye_metody/posobie)

Comment: Да. Я Ньютоном и пробывал делать.
Вопрос, как получить обратную матрицу для прямоугольной?

Comment: Обратная матрица может существовать только для квадратных матриц. <a href="http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обратная_матрица">Подробнее.</a>

Comment: Было принято решение, что из-за физических особнностей задачи, уравнениями в простых узлах в принципе можно пренебречь (это первое и четвертое) на этапе рассчета. Причем исключается только одно уравнение. Если же уравнений больше чем неизвестных на 2, то добавляется конструкция вида + х - у ( где две неизвестных, но они добавляются ко всем уравнениям и подразумевается, что они одинаковые. Хотя только сейчас появилась идея. Если уравнений нечетное, то можно добавть во все +х -у, и добавить ещё одно уравнение вида х-у = 0. Для получения квадратной матрицы.

Comment: Короче, всем спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Складываем первые четыре уравнения, получаем: 22 = 0.
Система несовместна.